# Show specific child row in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Let's say that I have a added 2 children to a datatable row using [row().child()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.child%28%29)

```
row.child([item1, item2]);
```

Later, I would like to show one of the children, without regenerating it. `row.child.show()` works fine, except that it shows *both* childs.

How to show a specific child from `row.child`?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mg22w6o5/

Try clicking the first generated row. How to only show one of the childs?

My current solution if it helps anyone: http://jsfiddle.net/mg22w6o5/4/

Comment: JSFiddle would be definitely helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Allright, please see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct API to selectively show or hide child rows. There is [row().child()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.child%28%29) that returns jQuery collection of all child `<tr>` rows though but it's not helpful in this situation.

The possible solution would be to recreate child rows as shown below:

```
var dummyChilds = [['child 1'], ['child 2']];

table.row(0).child(dummyChilds);

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var row = table.row(this);
    var children = row.child();

    if(children){
       var child = row.child;

       // Recreate children rows
       row.child(dummyChilds[0]);

       if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
           child.hide();
       } else {           
           child.show();
       }
    }
} );
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg22w6o5/2/) for demonstration.

Comment: As I thought then. Thanks for confirming it. I ended up creating and showing the childs once using the datatables API (has do use ´child.show()´to get them added to the DOM), then toggling the childs visibility using jQuery.

Comment: My current solution (simplified): http://jsfiddle.net/mg22w6o5/4/ . Seems to work fine. Any obvious downsides?

Comment: @Johan, your solution is great, I could not find any flaws. Sorting, filtering and pagination seems to be all working and not affecting the child rows.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by number of the node:

```
row.childNodes[0];
```

If you have unique id's or classes there is also find() in jquery.

Comment: Thanks, but the `row` is an object returned by datatables. Since it's not a DOM element, it doesn't have a `childNodes` property. Even if it did, the childs aren't added to the DOM until the first use of `row.child.show()`, so I wouldn't find them anyway.